# React Typescript + Ant Design version 5.2.0 . The classes applied on ant design components takes a while to load

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have created a demo ant design + React project . But when I write my custom CSS classes and use it on **className** props of ant Design components . It is taking a fraction of a second to apply those styles. The same styles work if i pass it as inline using **styles** prop. Can anyone please tell me what is causing this behavior?

Code samples -

`<Row justify={'space-between'} className="margin-top-4" >`

The above code the margin top class is applied after a flicker of normal antd styles while page load

```
 <Row
    justify={'space-between'}

    styles={{marginTop:'1rem'}}
  >
```

The above code works without any flickering of ant designs styles

I tried using inline styles instead of classNames and it worked. I want to know why this behavior is occuring

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because they stopped using the less since v5 for better support of dynamic themes, refer [official doc](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5)